# Conditionally render Vue Elements or Higher Order Components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm in a bit of a pickle. Any help would be great

I've been on this for some time now, and I tried different things before I turn to you. You are my last line of defense.

**Problem:**

I have Vue page set up with VueRouter, and some basic JWT auth.
I want to render a `Header` element on some pages but not others.

I tried with `v-if` but it's messy and doesn't feel right.

I tried this answer:
[How to render header and sidebar after login using Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58313924/how-to-render-header-and-sidebar-after-login-using-vue)
but past the login page, it renders blank pages

here are examples (simplified)

**App.js :**

```
<template >
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       name: "app"
    }
</script>
```

**router/index.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import Home from './view/Home.vue'
import Login from './view/Login.vue'
import PageContainer './container/PageContainer.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  path: '/',
    component: () => import('../container/PageContainer.vue'),
    children: [ 
      { 
        path: '',
        name: "home",
        component: () => Home
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/'
      }
    ]
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
  const publicPages = ['/login'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token');

  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    return next('/login');
  }

  next();
})

export default router
```

**PageContainer :**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <Header/>
        <div class="main">
            <Navbar/>
            <section class="page">
               <router-view/>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './Navbar.vue'
import Header from './Header.vue'

export default {
    name: "container",
    components: {
        Navbar,
        Header
    }
}
</script>
```

If I try to go to base url, the `Login` page renders properly based on the `router.beforeEach` condition.
After a successful login and JWT storage, it:

- hits the `beforeEach`
- doesn't go into the condition
- should hit `next()` but the page doesn't get redirected?

I like the router version of the solution more than the `v-if` which makes me check for the token, say that there is already a user or not and based on that render the pages, but it doesn't feel right? I tried a bunch of other stupid stuff trying to get it to work, but no avail.

I'm relatively new to Vue, so any input would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. Trial and error.
I changed the `routes` variable slightly in the `router/index.js` and it worked.
If anyone needs this, I'll leave it here.

For some reason it had an issue on rendering a nameless arrow function but it didn't actually throw an error in the console.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  path: '/',
    component: PageContainer,
    children: [ 
      { 
        path: '',
        name: "home",
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/'
      }
    ]
]
```

Cheers!

Comment: The arrow function would be ok.  The path is different from the path when importing the same component at the top.  One in `components` folder, one in `layout`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I put layout for clarity for stackoverflow, but they are both in components hehe sorry about that. Thanks for catching it though, it's appreciated